# What's happenig behind the scene so the code returns 1 and not 43?

Tags: c#

Found this in one book, but the explanation was too short.

```
public class Program
{
    int a = 0;

    private static void Main()
    {
        var val = new Program();
        val.a += val.Foo();

        Console.WriteLine(val.a);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    private int Foo()
    {
        a = a + 42;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Does it have to do something with boxing or not?

Comment: `return 1` is probably not what you wanted.

Comment: It's a quiz from a book.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This doesn't have anything to do with boxing, it is order of operations...

```
class Program
{
    int a = 0;

    static void Main()
    {
        Program val = new Program();
        val.a += val.Foo();
        Console.WriteLine(val.a);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    int Foo()
    {
        a = a + 42;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

So what happens is

```
val.a += val.Foo();
```

Is essentially re-written as

```
val.a = val.a + val.Foo();
```

Because of order of operations, here is what gets pushed on the stack:

```
val.a = 0
val.Foo = 1
```

So when the evaluation of `val.a += val.Foo()` begins, it saves the current value of `val.a`, which is zero, then calls the function. The function modifies `val.a`, but because it is a value type, it does not update the saved value in the original caller. Once `val.Foo()` returns, the equation then becomes `val.a = 0 + 1`, hence the result is `1` and not `43`.

If it were re-written slightly, you would get a different result:

```
val.a = val.Foo() + val.a;
```

Would then result in 43. This is an order-of-operations problem.

Answer (score 3):

Let's have a look:

```
 // val.a = 0
 Program val = new Program(); 
 // val.a += val.Foo()           can be rewritten as 
 // val.a = val.a + val.Foo()    or initial value of val.a + result of val.Foo()
 // val.a = 0 + 1 
 val.a += val.Foo();  
 // print out 1 
 Console.WriteLine(val.a);
```

**Edit:** If you want to exploit *side effect* (assigning `a` to `42` within `Foo()` method), you can put (instead of `val.a = val.a + val.Foo()`):

```
 // result of val.Foo + current val.a value 
 // 1 + 42 == 43
 val.a = val.Foo() + val.a;
```

Comment: Yeah I thought it was going to be 42 + 1 because `a` was modified in `Foo()`, but since the operation already had a 0 before calling `Foo()` the operation was going to be 0+1 instead of 42+1. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

On `Foo()` you always return 1.

Correct code:

```
int Foo()
{
    a = a + 42;
    return a;
}
```

Comment: You missed the point of the exercise, it is showing how the order of operations work, the intended code is correct, the demonstration is that `a` becomes `1`, not `43` after it is called.

Comment: Actually, your question says "the code returns 1 and not 43".  The only `return` statement in your code is `return 1;`.  It's pretty obvious why it happens.  Was this an "exercise"; you wrote deliberately confusing code and asked people why it's behaving the way it is?  And, if you want to know why the code is writing a particular value to the console, you should ask that, not talk about "return".